# The Sims 3: Athletic skill stuck, any way to fix?

Tags: the-sims-3

In The Sims 3, I have a sim that plainly refuses to learn the athletic skill. She can work out for hours, get fatigued, but her skill meter never moves and the skill is still stuck at zero.
I've installed the latest patch (1.18.9). No expansion packs, no mods, no items.

Is there any way to fix this?

Things I've tried so far:

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>,
  `resetSim <name of sim>`
  This had no effect other than resetting the sim's position.
- Going to the stadium to learn the athletic skill
  This only blocked the sim from doing the same thing again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this was caused by an application update (from 1.8.5 to 1.18.9).
I have decided to start a new neighborhood from scratch and have not encountered the problem again.